# jGRASP wedge error: command "bcc32" not found

Tags: java, jgrasp

CompSci student here. for some reason, my jGRASP won't run. After I compile the code it give this error message

"
----jGRASP exec: bcc32 -IC:\Borland\BCC55\Include -LC:\Borland\BCC55\lib;C:\Borland\BCC55\lib\psdk -n. -etest.exe test.cpp
 ----jGRASP wedge error: command "bcc32" not found.
 ----   This command must be in the current Working directory
 ----   or on the current PATH to use this function.
 ----   working directory is "D:\Structured Programming".
 ----   PATH is "C:\Borland\BCC55\Bin;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Hazlan Shah\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;".
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
"

I have tried a lot of fixes including manually changing the path and re downloading and reinstalling everything, but for some reason, nothing seems to work.

Is there something I'm missing, or is this a bug I can fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the Borland C++ compiler? If you are and it is not installed in C:\Borland\BCC55\Bin, use "Settings" > "PATH / CLASSPATH" > "Workspace" (or project if you are using a project) to add its bin directory to the path. If you want to be able to use the compiler from the command line also, add it to the Windows system path instead.

If you are using some other compiler, use "Settings" > "Compiler Settings" > "Workspace" (or project), select language C++ if not already selected, and change the compiler environment. The default environment will work for MinGW, Cygwin, and other GCC-based compilers. You will also need their bin directory to be on the path either for Windows or for jGRASP as above.